# URL issue after setting up Custom Structure in Settings >> Permalinks

Tags: customization, permalinks, taxonomy, urls

I've tried to Google this but to no avail. I'm a newbie at programming but I can say I'm adept at configuring WP - pretty please, please bear with me. :)

I have a **CUSTOM_TAXONOMY** that when viewed, the archive's url is `example.com/custom_taxonomy/actual_taxonomy/`.

Since I wanted my posts to have this new custom taxonomy's slug in all my post urls, I went to `Settings >> Permalinks` in WP dashboard and set it to **"Custom Structure"** of `example.com/%custom_taxonomy%/%postname%/`, I am able to actually get my goal of having standard posts with that url scheme.

However, when I was about to create a wp page with url: `example.com/actual_taxonomy` to properly display the archives for my custom taxonomy with some few added designs, it seems that  example.com/custom_taxonomy is turned into an auto-archive, with the same layout as the one in the second paragraph above.

I really wanted to create my own page and set the url as `example.com/actual_taxonomy`, however it's already there because I've set it in `Settings >> Permalinks`. Is there any way to avoid this issue? Much thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, you're looking to list out taxonomies on one page and you already set URL for post(s).

This [URL](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/) can help with creating custom taxonomy page.
Go through it and I'm sure that's your solution.

Comment: Thanks @Milan! I went through the site and I understood about templates, however in this case I want to be able to edit the page example.com/actual_taxonomy without it already being the archive for the relevant taxonomy.